# How can I make a file un-hidden permanently?

Tags: finder, macos

I have some files that were hidden on a PC. Now they live on my Mac. How can I remove the hidden property on each of these files?

Comment: Windows extended ACLs (like Read-Only, Hidden, System, etc.) don't translate 1:1 to OS X's HFS ACLs. Could you elaborate on this question? Screenshots/use cases/elaboration and all that are wonderful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Terminal `defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE`, relaunch  Finder. After that you'll see all your hidden files in Finder.

Now type

```
chflags nohidden
```

into Terminal and just drag&drop file that you want to unhide on the line. Enter.

`defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles FALSE` will reverse Finder back to normal.